# Make HttpRequest cache work

Tags: c#, caching, httprequest

I want to force HttpRequest response to be cached absolutely without any conditions. But it seems like sometimes it doesn't work. May be it looks at headers but I don't want it to. For an example [this url](http://eve-utils.net/maps/shortest_path/?origin_type=origin_system&origin_system=Austraka&destination_type=destination_system&destination_system=Gerek&avoid_lowsec=on&maximum_security=None&avoid_systems=&avoid_regions=&align_time=&warp_speed=&ship_speed=) is not cached sometimes. Here is a code:

```
public static class HttpRequestHelper
{
    public const string ContentTypeForm = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    public static HttpWebRequest CreateRequest(Uri uri)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(uri);
        request.Proxy = null;
        return request;
    }

    public enum CacheMode
    {
        None = 0,
        Hourly,
        Max,
    }

    public static string Request(Uri uri, CacheMode cache = CacheMode.None)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = CreateRequest(uri);
        if (cache != CacheMode.None)
            request.CachePolicy = new HttpRequestCachePolicy(HttpCacheAgeControl.MaxStale,
                cache == CacheMode.Hourly ? TimeSpan.FromHours(1) : TimeSpan.FromDays(365));
        return GetContent(request);
    }

    public static HttpWebResponse GetResponse(HttpWebRequest request)
    {
        Contract.Requires(request != null);
        Debug.WriteLine("Request: " + request.RequestUri);
        var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        return response;
    }


    public static string GetContent(WebRequest request)
    {
        Contract.Requires(request != null);
        string data = "";
        using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            if (responseStream == null) return data;
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
            {
                data = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Another url example http://games.chruker.dk/eve_online/item.php?type_id=17219

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely reason is server's response specifies some sort of "don't cache" headers. I.e. it could be `Pragma: no-cache` - so item will not be cached despite your efforts.

Possible workaround is to cache results yourself in-memory or on disk...

Comment: Can you suggesy any ready to use solutions? I don't want to implement all this stuff - cache database file and operations with it, managing what to keep in memory and etc.

Comment: Implemented it. Was not so difficult.